# What's going to happen with my questions when they're deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've read that some questions are deleted after some time due to low number of upvotes. If this happens, will it be possible to retrieve them some way?

I guess some of my questions may not have a big number of upvotes, but it will be helpy to keep them for my lifetime.

Comment: When questions are deleted they go to questions heaven, when they are eternally upvoted and answered...

Comment: @AsafKaragila [What if I told you...](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/29546364.jpg)

Comment: @GustavoBandeira What if I told you I don't believe in tables.  Would they cease to exist?

Comment: @Graphth The opposite is also reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Questions that meet the following criteria are automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/151385):

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments

So questions that have at least one answer or one upvote (and don't belong to a deleted user) are safe from automatic deletion.

Closed questions can be deleted by the community, but open questions with a non-negative score are rarely deleted at all.

And yes, moderators can retrieve deleted questions. 10k+ users in theory as well, but they need a direct link to find the question.

Comment: I remember of reading that they're deleted after one year. Not so sure about that.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I've added the exact criteria for deletion. I forgot about the 365 day criteria as they rarely come up. The criteria are pretty strict, only unanswered questions that are pretty much completely ignored by the community will get deleted.